# My WPF DataGrid is being styled but I don't know where it is doing that

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

We have a WPF application with multiple teams sharing assemblies to develop an integrated application. Some windows in our application are WPF and XAML.

Today I integrated some DLLs into our application from another team and suddenly, my DataGrid is being styled differently. It is also giving me runtime errors where the DataGrid is showing zero columns, when I know very well that I add columns dynamically in my code during runtime.

What could be causing this?

Is it possible that someone in our team is creating a global style for all DataGrids? Now my DataGrids are being affected?

I am not an expert in WPF but that is my guess. Can this be possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is possible. However, it's not possible to tell more because you don't provide any other details.

Comment: You may try to set the Style property of the `DataGrid` to `x:Null` to fallback to the default `Style`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, check the other teams for generic styles being put into app.xaml as that seems pretty common, otherwise make sure they know to only style for specific groups (ie a datagrid on a page referencing a particular style for a page/window)

With no more info I cannot help you any further other than to remove the dlls and show it works, then add them and show it doesn't. Make sure your own styles are not enforcing anything onto all datagrids (as that could give you an error if it applies it to any in the DLLs).

Comment: I followed this procedure and yes, I was able to prove they were applying styles to other teams' pages.